# Image cropping in email HTML?

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm wondering if there are any restrictions about **image cropping** in email HTML. I've already tried to set `width` and `height` properties but that didn't work. I also tried the `Clip property` and that didn't work either.

The image in both situations keeps showing it entire content.

Comment: Is it variable how the image would be displayed (for instance, at different viewing widths)? Or do you just want to show part of the image to all? Email clients can be picky with the former (maybe `overflow: hidden` on the parent "frame", `background-image` on the "framing element", etc.). The latter, just crop the file to size manually.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the variations in HTML rendering each email client will render it differently. You will need to treat your HTML email as if there is no CSS and uses basic HTML.

The best option would be to manually crop the image using an image editor.

Advanced CSS would not be a trustworthy avenue and should be avoided to ensure cross platform/browser/client constancy.

Answer (score 1):

You should be more concerned if you are supporting from Microsoft Outlook 2007 which doesn't offer support for CSS. It renders based on Microsoft Office rendering engine due to security issues which is lame enough to understand even CSS2 tags. So I would also go with the above comment to manually crop the image using an image editor.

```
Tip:
```

For Email testing I have used http://www.emailonacid.com/ even though it is paid version it does the email testing easier.